# "para" vs "de" vs "a"

Tags: preposiciones

I'm trying to say the following in Spanish: "Apart from the bus and its inability to function..."

I have the following options and I'm not sure which is correct:

> Aparte de la guagua y su incapacidad **de** funcionar
>
> Aparte de la guagua y su incapacidad **a** funcionar
>
> Aparte de la guagua y su incapacidad **para** funcionar

Note: I'm using "guagua" because I'm writing a paper about a movie from Cuba, where they use "guagua" instead of "autobús."

Comment: I think that in Spain, just in the Canary Islands, they use _guagua_ too, instead of _autobús_.

Comment: And both islands have the same accent, Cuba's accent is from the Canary Islands.

Comment: I'm from Cuba, what movie it's about?

Comment: http://www.muyinteresante.es/cultura/arte-cultura/articulo/ipor-que-se-llama-guaguas-a-los-autobuses-en-canarias

Comment: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15849/10864 may assist

Answer (score 1):

You can use either *de* or *para*. If you do the Google search `incapacidad site:rae.es` you'll find that both are used rather indistinctly in DRAE's own definitions:

- Incapacidad del macho **para** fecundar (esterilidad)
- Incapacidad **para** escribir, debida a una lesión cerebral (agrafía)
- Síndrome infantil caracterizado por la incapacidad congénita **de** establecer contacto verbal... (autismo)
- Incapacidad **para** percibir los colores (acromatopsia)
- Incapacidad **de** escribir de un modo correcto los sonidos percibidos... (disgrafia)
- Incapacidad parcial o total **para** comprender lo que se lee... (dislexia)
- Falta de solvencia, incapacidad **de** pagar una deuda (insolvencia)
- Incapacidad **de** engendrar o concebir (impotencia)

The same happens with *capacidad*. Note that if instead of the noun you use the adjective [*incapaz*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=incapaz), then in this case you can only use *de*:

- Esta guagua es incapaz **de** funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `para` in this case. You want to express the ability (or inability) of an agent (the bus) to do an action, duty or fulfill its purpose (work/function/run) and `Para` is the preposition that is used to indicate the purpose of something (in this case "to work" or "function").

> Aparte de la guagua y su incapacidad **para funcionar**

Other examples of the use of `para` to show purpose:

> Esta máquina sirve **para hacer café** <sub>This machine is meant to make coffee</sub>
>
> He comprado este líquido **para limpiar** los cristales <sub>I bought this liquid to clean the windows</sub>
>
> Ese mando a distancia no vale **para** la tele, es el del DVD (implies "para hacer funcionar/manipular la televisión") <sub>This remote wont work to operate the TV, it is for the DVD player</sub>
>
> Este trabajo me viene bien **para conseguir** experiencia <sub>This job is good for me to get some experience</sub>
>
> Juan estudia para abogado (implies "**para ser** abogado") <sub>Juan studies to be a lawyer</sub>

Comment: En este caso, *a* es una alternativa a para.  Antes se consideraba un galicismo total, pero ya con tanto uso en los periódicos, la RAE lo admite.  Pero claramente, *para* es preferible y más natural al idioma.