# What are the more complex meanings of "de"?

Tags: gramática, definiciones, preposiciones, polisemia

So, I already know basic forms of this word (of, from, etc.), but I keep seeing it used in places that I don't understand. For example, I sometimes see "antes de que", or just "de que". Why does "de" need to be in there?

I also see it used with some verbs, and not with others.

I'd like to know the other uses of this word besides the standard definition.

Comment: That "de" before the "que" is so tricky that even native Spanish speakers don't always use them correctly. We call it [_dequeismo_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=vTr05If13D6tGOqCWV) when there should NOT be a "de" before the "que" and someone actually puts it there. The contrary (not having the "de" when is needed before the "que") is called [_queismo_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=0WI0lLaCjD655ud6n5). Maybe this latter link could give you some insight about when or why "de" (sometimes) must precede "que" (and when it shouldn't).

Comment: Also, you might find [this other question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/61/5481) useful.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is strictly in the "**que** vs **de que**" context. Of course, **de** can have a whole bunch of other meanings depending on the context, as just like the English "of", **de** happens to be a part of dozens of idiomatic expressions. If you're curious of exploring those idiomatic expressions, any online dictionary should come in handy. I find [Spanishdict](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/de) and [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=de) quite organized and easy to look up. If you're particularly curious about the difference between **de** and **de que**, read on.

**This post comes from here, I think it explains it in a comprehensive way. This is what it says:**
***Source***: [spanish.about.com/od/partsofspeech/a/que_vs_de_que.htm](http://spanish.about.com/od/partsofspeech/a/que_vs_de_que.htm)

> See the following two pairs of examples:
>
> - **El plan *que* quiere es caro.** *The plan **that** he wants is expensive.*
> - **El plan *de que* los estudiantes participen en las actividades es caro.** *The plan **that** students participate in the activities is
>     expensive.*
>
> Structurally, both sentences follow this pattern:
>
> - **English**: subject of sentence ("the plan") + dependent clause beginning with "that"
> - **Spanish**: subject of sentence ("el plan") + dependent clause beginning with **que** or **de que**
>
> The grammatical difference between those may not be obvious, but in
>   the first one, **que** translates "that" as a relative pronoun, while
>   in the second **de que** translates "that" as a conjunction.
>
> Although **que** can be used as a subordinate or subordinating
>   conjunction when it follows a verb, **de que** normally is used as a
>   subordinating conjunction following a noun.
>
> So how can you tell if you're translating a sentence of this pattern
>   to Spanish if "that" should be translated as **que** or **de que**?
>   Almost always, if you can change "that" to "which" and the sentence
>   still makes sense, "that" is being used as a relative pronoun and you
>   should use **que**.
>
> Otherwise, use **de que**. See how in the following sentences either
>   "which" or "that" makes sense in English (although "that" is preferred
>   by many grammarians):
>
> - **Es una nación *que* busca independencia.** *It is a country **that**/**which** is seeking independence.*
> - **No hay factores de riesgo *que* se puedan identificar para la diabetes tipo 1.** *There are no risk factors **that**/**which** can
>     be identified for Type 1 diabetes.*
> - **La garantía *que* brinda General Motors es aplicable a todos los vehículos nuevos marca Chevrolet.** *The guarantee **that**/**which**
>     General Motors offers is applicable to all new Chevrolet-brand
>     vehicles.*
>
> And here are some examples of **de que** being used as a conjunction.
>   Note how the "that" of the English translations can't be replaced by
>   "which":
>
> - **El calcio reduce el riesgo *de que* el bebé nazca con problemas de peso.** *Calcium reduces the risk **that** the baby is born with
>     weight problems.*
> - **Hay señales de alarma *de que* un niño está siendo abusado.** *There are warning signs **that** a child is being abused.*
> - **No hay ninguna garantía *de que* esta estrategia pueda funcionar.** *There is no guarantee **that** this strategy can work.*
> - **Ecuador admite posibilidad *de que* jefes de las Farc estén en su territorio.** *Ecuador is admitting the possibility **that** FARC
>     leaders are in its territory.*
> - **La compañía quiere convencernos *de que* su producto es ideal para los jugadores empedernidos.** *The company wants to convince us
>     **that** its product is idea for hard-core gamers.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Plagiarism - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your answer being down-voted or deleted. http://spanish.about.com/od/partsofspeech/a/que_vs_de_que.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think that deeper, more profound answers require one to appeal to Linguistics. So I Googled ["semantics of spanish prepositions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22semantics+of+spanish+prepositions%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=xQyjVoKBJMef-wHf0re4BA) which revealed the following that should assist:

Huerta, Beth Lynn (2009). *The semantics of the spanish prepositions en, a, and de: A cognitive approach* (Order No. 3372152).
Available from ProQuest Dissertations & Theses A&I. (305085088).
Retrieved from http://search.proquest.com/docview/305085088?accountid=9851

At 24 pages, it is too long to reproduce here, but these  details that should aid you to find it:
It  is dated June 26, 2009, and

> A dissertation submitted to the 
>   Faculty of the Graduate School of the 
>   University at Buffalo, State University of New York 
>   in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the  degree of 
>   Doctor of Philosophy

A partial quote from p 11 of 24 (Abstract) should already convince you of and to evidence its helpfulness:

> Prepositions are a source of error for English-speakers learning Spanish throughout many 
>   years of study. Other than contrasts of 
>   *por* 
>   and 
>   *para*
>   , very little emphasis is given to the 
>   semantics of prepositions in current SLA pr
>   actices. However, a preposition in either 
>   Spanish or English may have several meanings
>    associated with it which a native speaker 
>   would know and use. Since prepositions in 
>   both languages have multiple meanings which 
>   do not entirely equate to the most similar pre
>   position in the other language, at times there 
>   is a match (equivalency) and at other tim
>   es there is a mismatch between the two 
>   languages. English-speaking learners of Spanis
>   h may attempt to equate the prepositions 
>   across languages if unaware of the differences in spatial relations coded by the 
>   prepositions in the two languages.
>      This dissertation examines the prepositions 
>   *en*, *a*, and *de* in consideration of the 
>   subset of spatial relations that they form within the Spanish language, their primary 
>   meanings, and the semantic network of meanings associated with them. By using 
>   illustrations and explanations of spatial relations for the three Spanish prepositions as 
>   determined by Whitley, explanations of 
>   the system provided by Bull, semantic 
>   descriptions provided by the 
>   Diccionario de la Real Academia Española
>    and the 
>   Diccionario de Construcción y Ré
>   gimen de la Lengua Castellana
>   , and by applying the 
>   model of principled polysemy
>    for analyzing English prepositions proposed by Tyler and 
>   Evans,  the current work provides a thorough description of 
>   en
>   , 
>   a
>   , and 
>   de 
>   from a cognitive perspective, that is, in terms of the 
>   concepts 
>   they convey. In order to provide a more complete analysis for the learner and educator, this work also includes a very brief 
>   description of grammaticalized usages of these prepositions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's better to, and more understandable to a beginner/intermediate speaker, to combine the `de` with `antes` -- `antes de`.

> - Before running, I stretch.
> - Antes de correr me estiro.

If you wanted append this to a clause or something like that, then you could get fancy and use `antes de que`.. `before [conjugated verb here]`

> Before I run, I stretch.
>   Antes de que corro me estiro.

You could get even fancier

> - Joe whines before he has to do anything.
> - Joe grita antes de que tenga que hacer algo.

`Antes de` is followed by a verb in the infinitive (not conjugated).
`Antes de que` precedes a clause with a conjugated verb.

If you use `antes` without `de` then it means `beforehand`.. and can typically leave a listener/reader anticipating a `de` or `que`, but if the context is there, then it will make sense

> Carlos put on the mittens after grabbing the hot pan from the stove.
>
> You're supposed to put them on beforehand!
>
> Carlos se puso los mitones después de agarrar la bandeja del horno.
>
> ¡Hay que ponerlos antes!