# When to translate "at" to "a" instead of "en"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, preposiciones

I've noticed that sometimes at can be translated to "a" instead of "en," and I think that I have a pretty good idea of when to use which, but, even after doing some diligent Googling, I can't seem to figure out what the rule is, if there is any.

Examples

> I went to leave my friend **at** the airport.
>
> Fui a dejar a mi amigo **al** aeropuerto.

or

> We're going through security **at** the airport.
>
> Pasamos por seguridad **en** el aeropuerto.

Is there any rule that says when which preposition should be used?

Comment: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15849/10864 may assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a question for each sentence:

> Fui ***a*** dejar a mi amigo. ¿***A*** dónde? ***Al*** aeropuerto.
>
> Pasamos ***por*** seguridad. ¿***En*** dónde? ***En*** el aeropuerto.

If you say

> Fui a dejar a mi amigo en el aeropuerto.

You are saying that you left your friend somewere but in the airport as if you were using a car.

> Fui a dejar a mi amigo ***en el coche***.

You used the car to leave your friend.

And if you say

> Pasamos por seguridad al aeropuerto.

You didin't passed throught security, the airport is the one who is passing throught security by your action. Or you went to the airport to get some security or picking up security.

As far as I can understand, use **a** if the action ends in the place or thing and **en** if the action occurs in the place or thing.

> Fuimos a la tienda. Ends in the store
>
> Compramos en la tienda. Happened in the store.

Comment: Making questions helps but you should add to the answer that there is no rule. Prepositions are like that. You should learn them by using them on sentences and not by applying rules.